# create new uiview dynamically.on click of uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

i want to create new view every time on click of button.
like when i first press button it will execute this code
which i tried

```
 let userResizableView1 = ZDStickerView()
```

so now when i click next time on this button it should be create new view again with name userResizableView2 so how can i do this?

Comment: You can't create a variable with a different name. You need to use an array

Answer (score 0):

While you can't create a new name for the variable per se, what you could do is create a new view each time that has a new identifier.

So you could do something like this:

```
var views: [ZDStickerView] = [ZDStickerView]()

func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    let view = ZDStickerView()
    view.accessibilityIdentifier = "userResizableView" + String(views.count + 1)
    views.append(view)
}
```

This way you find this specific view again.

For reference, it might be easier if you are willing to use the `.tag` property which would look more like:

```
view.tag = views.count + 1
```

However, you could have problems with this if you were to alter the array later on since the tags would not be in order. I don't know how you are applying this, but just be wary.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you have explained above in your question is not possible because you are requiring **dynamic name of a variable** which is not supported by `iOS`.
But the logic can be developed for your requirement as:
**1)** You can create an array, globally to store your view.
**2)** When you click on a button then add a view in the globally declared array.
**3)** When you require your view, you can access the same by passing an relavent index.
for example,
you click your button for the first time, add a view in the array.
Now your array contain 1 object.
When you click your button 2nd time, your array contain 2 objects, and so on...
Now,
When you require your 2nd view then you can access

```
 [<"YourArrayName"> objectAtIndex:2];
```